# How to convert date to UTC format of -05:30?

Tags: jquery

I have a start date, start time, end date and end time as a string.

```
var startdate = "2015-05-27";
var startTime = "05:30:00"
var endDate = "2015-05-28";
var endTime = "20:30:00";
```

I have to convert those time to UTC format in -5:30 hours.How can I do it ?

Comment: What have you searched or tried using jquery?

Comment: Because i should do in client side not in server side